# Page in Firefox strange behaviour designMode - disable enableInlineTableEditing, enableInlineTableEditing

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, designmode

I have 2 problem with strange behaviour of page http://www.zora2.pl/m1/ in firefox.

1. table tag and img tag was resizeble, i found that it is designMode enabled. I disabled it with code:

```js
<script>
document.designMode = "on";
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, "false");
document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", false, "false");
document.designMode = "off"; 
</script>
```

content is no longer editable

**2. But links are still editable not clickable - try first pdf file in table. It has a tag but it is not clickable in firefox. It works in chrome and opera. Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

One of parent elements had contenteditable="true":
I changed it to:

```
<div class="entry-content wzt-editable" data-content_type="content" contenteditable="false">
```

and all works fine. I home somebody use it as solution.